# How to fix xclock command not found error on Oracle Linxu 6.4?

Tags: software-installation, oracle-linux

I want to do GUI based installation but xclock command is not found. I have checked, I don't have xclock at all by finding it.

```
 # xclock
-bash: xclock: command not found
```

If I search x11 I found following:

```
# find / -name X11
/usr/lib64/X11
/usr/share/X11
/etc/X11
```

I don't think Xorg X11 is installed, because I can't see bin path of X11 in my PATH variable.

So the challenge is to install this package on my box. It does not have internet so I can not run yum command.

X11 Forwarding is also yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Anyone can tell me the RPM URL to download and install?

And suggestion what's the way out.

I am using following distribution.

Output of /proc/version file:

```
Oracle Linux Server release 6.4
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
```

Answer (score 4):

Oracle Linux derives from RHEL/CentOS so I would expect the application to be available in a similarly named package. Searching on a CentOS 6.x system I have here turns up the following package:

```
$ repoquery -q -f */xclock
xorg-x11-apps-0:7.6-6.el6.x86_64
```

You can peak inside packages using `repoquery` if you know the name like so:

```
$ repoquery -q -l xorg-x11-apps.x86_64 | grep xclock
/usr/bin/xclock
/usr/share/man/man1/xclock.1.gz
```

To install:

```
$ yum install xorg-x11-apps.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to resolve this issue after installing the library `xorg-x11-apps`.

Run the command as root user:

```
yum install xorg-x11-apps
```